# Seg Fault in pthread_mutex_init()

Tags: c, synchronization, segmentation-fault, pthreads, mutex

I need to put locks on an NxN matrix with varying levels of granularity.  I am getting a segmentation fault in the pthread_mutex_init() function when initializing the grid-level lock.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXGRIDSIZE     10
#define MAXTHREADS      1000
#define NO_SWAPS        20
#define MIN(X,Y)        ((X < Y) ? X : Y)
#define MAX(X,Y)        ((X > Y) ? X : Y)

extern int errno;

typedef enum {GRID, ROW, CELL, NONE} grain_type;
const int gridsize = 0;
int grid[MAXGRIDSIZE][MAXGRIDSIZE];
int threads_left = 0;
time_t start_t, end_t;

pthread_mutex_t grid_lock;
pthread_mutex_t *row_lock;
pthread_mutex_t **cell_lock;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        printf("GOOD\n");

        int nthreads = 0;
        pthread_t threads[MAXTHREADS];
        grain_type rowGranularity = NONE;
        long initSum = 0, finalSum = 0;
        int i,j;

        printf(" arg[0]:%s \n arg[1]:%s \n arg[2]:%s \n arg[3]:%s \n",argv[0], argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]);

        /*get dimensions for n x n matrix*/
        int gridsize = atoi(argv[1]);

        printf("PAST atoi\n");

        pthread_mutex_init(&grid_lock,NULL);

        printf("grid_lock initialized");

        row_lock = (pthread_mutex_t*) malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)*gridsize);

        for(i = 0; i < gridsize; i++){
            pthread_mutex_init(&row_lock[i],NULL);
        }

        cell_lock = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t*)*gridsize);

        for(i = 0; i < gridsize; i++){
            cell_lock[i] = malloc(sizeof(pthread_mutex_t)*gridsize);

            for(j = 0; j < gridsize; i++)
                pthread_mutex_init(&cell_lock[i][j],NULL);
        }
```

The error is in the line "pthread_mutex_init(&grid_lock,NULL);" according to GDB and the surrounding printf statements.  I have looked at a few of my friends' code that is nearly identical, but they don't have any issues.  I am completely lost on a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your inner loop is using the wrong incrementor:

```
for(j = 0; j < gridsize; i++)
// this -----------------^
```

Should be this:

```
for(j = 0; j < gridsize; j++)
// that -----------------^
```

Oh cut-and-paste, ye art a cruel and heartless wench.

Comment: Probably should mentioned this, voted to close as this is clearly a typo, but at least you now know why.

Comment: Agreed. And to add the reason for the OP's misinterpretation of where the error occurrs: If `printf("grid_lock initialized");` would be `printf("grid_lock initialized\n");` the log-message wouldn't get stuck in `stdout`'s buffer, but be printed and it would become obvious that the bug in **not** inside the "*the surrounding printf statements**". Lessons learned: **Always** `fprintf()` debug messages to `stderr`, as it's unbuffered by default.

Comment: Yea, I realized the typo and fixed all the code.  Is working fine now.  Thanks for the tip about the debugging statements though!  At least I got some kind of knowledge from my stupid mistake.